# Open multiple tabs with java script in IE 11 without UrlReferrer equaling null

Tags: javascript, url, tabs, internet-explorer-11

There are several questions and answers re this, but not one of them is working for me.
It is IE 11, chrome works fine of course, with just  window.open(url).

I can get only one tab to open, not several (They are opened by an iterative js piece of code).

```
for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++)
{
    url = "./Report/?reportName=" + reportName;
    url += "&id=" + "@Model.Header.ID";
    ShowInMultipleTabs(url, i);
}
```

I need the UrlReferrer to be non null, as it is used in our applications security.

A solution which works to a point, i.e. gets past the null urlReferrer issue, but only opens ONE new tab is;

```
function ShowInMultipleTabs(url, tabCounter)
{
    if ((url !== undefined) && (url !== ''))
    {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.target = "_about";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.setAttribute("id", "'" + tabCounter + "'");
        link.click();
    }
}
```

How can I get this to display all the tabs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special target name `_blank` is used to open links in a new tab or window. If you use some other string that is not known as a special key (as `_about` in your code), it is handled as a window name. When the named window/tab is not open yet, a new one will be opened. Otherwise the tab will be reused.

Also consider to use an ajax approach.